# Absolute URL from base + relative URL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, url, path

I have a base URL :

```
http://my.server.com/folder/directory/sample
```

And a relative one :

```
../../other/path
```

How to get the absolute URL from this ? It's pretty straighforward using string manipulation, but I would like to do this in a secure way, using the `Uri` class or something similar.

It's for a standard a C# app, not an ASP.NET one.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://my.server.com/folder/directory/sample");
var absoluteUri = new Uri(baseUri,"../../other/path");
```

OR

```
Uri uri;
if ( Uri.TryCreate("http://base/","../relative", out uri) ) doSomething(uri);
```

Comment: May I ask, is there any JavaScript equivalent of the code above?

Comment: One point noting, that for some unknown reason `new Uri` **decodes** html entities, and if this makes a difference, this will lead to incorrect URL. For example I have a page, lets say `hello%2Fworld.html` page. After making it absolute I get `hello/world.html` which is of course incorrect.

Comment: 42 votes but it doesn't work. First snipped yields: http://my.server.com/other/path which is missing the /folder/ part.

Comment: @MartinCapodici The OP specified a different base URI than for what you are specifying. In your case, you can can use `"http://my.server.com/folder/directory/sample/"` as the base URI.

Answer (score 0):

Some might be looking for Javascript solution that would allow conversion of urls 'on the fly' when debugging

```
var absoluteUrl = function(href) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = href;
    return link.href;
}
```

use like:

`absoluteUrl("http://google.com")`

> `http://google.com/`

or

`absoluteUrl("../../absolute")`

> `http://stackoverflow.com/absolute`