# Is there a .net library for parsing relative web addresses?

Tags: .net, url, parsing, relative-path

I am writing a search engine (why not hey?) and need to handle navigating relative urls such as "../about.aspx", "/about.aspx" "about.aspx" etc

Is there anything out there or in the .Net Library's which can convert these to absolute addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class, the [System.UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class, and the [System.HttpStyleUriParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.httpstyleuriparser.aspx) class

Comment: found duplicate question with a good answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128990/absolute-url-from-base-relative-url-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `system.uri`.