# How to resolve url with non-ancestor references

Tags: c#, url

I have urls with references to folders that are not direct ancestors of the page pointed to - like these below:

```
    http://www.mysite.com/home/../help/helppage.aspx

    http://www.mysite.com/contact/../help/helppage.aspx

    http://www.mysite.com/accounts/performing-accounts/../../help/helppage.aspx
```

I'd like to be able to unambiguously resolve these to

http://www.mysite.com/help/helppage.aspx.

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Please see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128990/absolute-url-from-base-relative-url-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/home/../help/helppage.aspx");
uri.AbsoluteUri; // <- Contains http://www.mysite.com/help/helppage.aspx
```