# Simplify a relative URL

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if someone else can come up with a better way of simplifying relative URLs on either the basis of `System.Uri` or other means that are available in the standard .NET framework. My attempt works, but is pretty horrendous:

```
public static String SimplifyUrl(String url)
{
    var baseDummyUri = new Uri("http://example.com", UriKind.Absolute);
    var dummyUri = new Uri(baseDummyUri , String.Join("/",
        Enumerable.Range(0, url.Split(new[] { ".." }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length)
                  .Select(i => "x")));

    var absoluteResultUri = new Uri(dummyUri, url);
    var resultUri = dummyUri.MakeRelativeUri(absoluteResultUri);
    return resultUri.ToString();
}
```

This gives, for example:

```
./foo -> foo
foo/./bar -> foo/bar
foo/../bar -> bar
```

The problem that makes this so awkward is that `Uri` itself doesn't seem to simplify URLs that are relative and `MakeRelativeUri` also only works on absolute URLs. So to trick the `Uri` class into doing what I want, I construct a base URL that has the appropriate amount of nesting.

I could also use `System.IO.Path`, but then I'd have to search-and-replace backlashes to slashes...

There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? What is a url you want to simplify, and what would the simplified url be?

Comment: @ScottHannen Added examples.

Comment: I think your solution is great.  It is probably the simplest method for doing the substitutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with one-liner:

```
new Uri(new Uri("http://example.com/"), url).AbsolutePath.TrimStart('/');
```

The following test shows the results:

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("./foo", "foo")]
        [InlineData("/foo", "foo")]
        [InlineData("foo", "foo")]
        [InlineData("foo/./bar", "foo/bar")]
        [InlineData("/foo/./bar", "foo/bar")]
        [InlineData("/foo/../bar", "bar")]
        [InlineData("foo/../bar", "bar")]
        public void Test(string url, string expected)
        {
            var result = new Uri(new Uri("http://example.com/"), url).AbsolutePath.TrimStart('/');
            Assert.Equal(expected, result);
        }
```

Of course, if you want to leave `/` in the beginning just remove `TrimStart('/')`

Answer (score 0):

This is a parsing problem. The tokens are separated by "/"; the token ".." reduces the previous token (if any) while the token "." is a no-op.

There's a little bit of a twist which is that after we break the string with "/" we need to keep track of whether it was an absolute path (starting at "/") or relative path (starting at "."). We need this in case the reduced path is empty.

```
public static class UrlHelper
{
    static public string Simplify(this string url)
    {
        string[] sourcePath = (url ?? "").Trim().Split('/');
        if (sourcePath.Count() == 0) { throw new ArgumentException(); }
        string startingAt = (sourcePath[0] == "")? "/": ".";

        Stack<string> simplifiedPath = new Stack<string>();
        foreach (string dir in sourcePath) {
            if (dir == ".") {
                continue;
            } else if (dir == ".." && simplifiedPath.Count > 0) {
                simplifiedPath.Pop();
                continue;
            }
            simplifiedPath.Push(dir);
        }
        string reducedPath = (simplifiedPath.Count == 0)? "": simplifiedPath.Reverse().Aggregate((path, dir) => path + "/" + dir);
        return (reducedPath == "") ? startingAt : reducedPath;
    }
}
```

A bit of testing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("./foo".Simplify());         // => foo
        Console.WriteLine("foo/./bar".Simplify());     // => foo/bar
        Console.WriteLine("foo/../bar".Simplify());    // => bar
        Console.WriteLine("foo/bar/../..".Simplify()); // => .
        Console.WriteLine("/foo/bar/../..".Simplify()); // => /
        Console.WriteLine("../bar".Simplify());        // => ../bar
        Console.WriteLine("..".Simplify());            // => ..
        Console.WriteLine(".".Simplify());             // => .
        Console.WriteLine("/foo".Simplify());          // => /foo
        Console.WriteLine("/".Simplify());             // => /
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: After I wrote this I noticed another answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128990/absolute-url-from-base-relative-url-in-c-sharp?rq=1